# for in construct

Tags: javascript

I recently stumbled upon this construct in Javascript:

```
function find(id) {
  var found = null;

  findloop: for (var index in products){
    var product = products[index];
    if (product.id === id) {
      found = product;
      break findloop;
    }
  };
  return found;
}
```

What bothers me is the `findloop:`
Is this even a legal syntax ? What is the point of it ?

thanks

Comment: There's a closing parenthesis missing in your if-statement.

Comment: Breaking to labels is just a named goto, preferably avoid it all cost. Any place where it is used can be and should be refactored to not use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, `findloop:` is a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label).  It can be referred to by `break` (as it is in your example), which can be useful when you have nested loops, and you want to break out of (one of) the outer loop(s).

In this case, it serves no useful purpose, since there is only one loop.